# Получить код страны: JS +API

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

При заходе пользователя на сайт мне не нужно получить значение кода его страны (из двух букв, в ISO 3166-1 Alpha 2 формате). К моему сожалению, РНР для реализации, в этом случае, невозможен. Нашел у Яндекса [вот такую штуку](https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.0-stable/?load=package.standard&lang=ru-RU)

Каким образом мне получить в переменную значение `["countryCode"]`? Нужен просто JS код, который передаст мне значение кода страны пользователя в переменную?

Если я изначально выбрал сложный/неправильный/нелогичный путь  - просьба подсказать более простое/быстрое/логичное решение.

Comment: Моя робкая попытка для YandexAPI:   
https://jsfiddle.net/7mce41yz/

Comment: Почему на PHP нельзя? Берет IP, потом через сервис CURL смотрите какой стране принадлежит IP. По умолчанию они как раз и передают двузначный код страны. Первый сервис в гугле: http://ip-api.com/json/31.23.115.9

Comment: @verng К сожалению, PHP использовать не получится, т.к. это серверный язык, а в данном случае, мы получаем этот контент из формы с помощью `file_get_contents`.  Если бы я мог использовать РНР - этот вопрос решался бы для меня элементарно.. %)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Более простой способ использовать API `geojs.io`:

```js
$.ajax({
  url: "https://get.geojs.io/v1/ip/geo.js",
  dataType: "jsonp",
  jsonpCallback:"geoip",
  success: function(data) {
    console.log("IP: "+data.ip);
    console.log("Country: "+data.country);
    console.log("Country Code: "+data.country_code);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Спасибо, проверил, это то что нужно!